# Google voice type offline doesn't work properly

Tags: voice-recognition

If I touch on voice type tool it shows me following message "Google voice typing tool requires Google search app" but  Google search app have been installed on my phone.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you modified your phone in any way? Custom ROMs? Rooting? Etc...

Comment: No I didn't it was working fine before hard reset

Comment: Is voice input enabled in your keyboard settings?

Comment: Sorry for the late response @xavier my keyboard setting doesn't have configuration for voice input and it was working fine while ago. I am having this problem since i hard reset my phone